# property 'target' does not exist on type 'htmlelement'

Tags: angular, typescript

I am trying to get id of a list item in select menu but ı can't get value from it. Value must be number.
HTML File

```
<div class="form-group mt-3">
    <label class="form-label">Ürün Kategori</label>
    <select class="form-control" #urunkatid>
      <option *ngFor="let kat of kategoriler" value="{{ kat.katId }}">
        {{ kat.katAdi }}
      </option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group mt-3">
    <button
      class="btn btn-success"
      (click)="
        UrunKaydet(urunadi.value, urunfiyat.value, urunkatid.target.value)
      "
    >
      Kaydet
    </button>
  </div>
```

TS File

```
UrunKaydet(ad: string, fiyat: string, katid: number) {
var yeni: Urun = new Urun();
yeni.urunId = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100);
yeni.urunAdi = ad;
yeni.urunKatId = katid;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Because `target` exists on event, not on your element.

Try `$event.target.value` instead:

```
    <button
      class="btn btn-success"
      (click)="
        UrunKaydet(urunadi.value, urunfiyat.value, $event.target.value)
      "
    >
```

Comment: no, i won't work. is there any other way to get option's value as number